# Kafka consumer get message as string from recovery context

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I created a config class for consumer with RetryTemplate and RecoveryCallback.

I want to just when works RecoveryCallback get consumer message as string. Anyway to do this?

```
  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
      ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer factoryConfigurer,
      ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factoryConfigurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
    factory.setRetryTemplate(kafkaRetry());
//    factory.setErrorHandler(kafkaErrorHandler);
    factory.setRecoveryCallback((context -> {
      ConsumerRecord record = (ConsumerRecord) context.getAttribute("record");
      log.info("Record value {}", record.value());
      System.out.println("========");
      System.out.println("========");
      return Optional.empty();
    }));
    return factory;
  }

  public RetryTemplate kafkaRetry() {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(backOffPeriod);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
    SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(maxAttempts);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(simpleRetryPolicy);
    return retryTemplate;
  }
```

Let me explain what I want to do. I want retry 3-4 times consume if not success when call fallback just save consumer message to database like json string. Just I cannot get message from consumer like json string in Fallback

Comment: Are you saying the callback is not getting called? Or that the `context` has no `record`?

Comment: Retry in the listener adapter is deprecated - see my answer.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Callback called I want get message and save to database like json string when fallback called.

Comment: @GaryRussell `record.value()` give me record but like char array. [1,2,3,4] like that.

Comment: It looks like you are using a `ByteArrayDeserializer` with the converted type being inferred from the listener method. So you will only get the raw unconverted data in the record. You can use a `ListenerErrorHandler` to get the converted `Message<?>`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.4-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#listener-error-handlers - or simply use `new String(record.value())`.

Comment: @GaryRussell yeah you are right. My bad I forget `ByteArrayDeserializer`. I changed just to `StringDeserializer`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that retry in the container factory/listener adapter is deprecated now that the error handlers have back offs and exception classification.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1886

The record is available in the record handler's recoverer.